# Easing d3-zoom drag behaviour

Tags: d3.js

How do you ease the drag gesture in `d3-zoom`?

I have set up a fairly standard implementation of `d3-zoom`, similar to this [observable](https://observablehq.com/@d3/drag-zoom?collection=@d3/d3-zoom).

```
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const group = d3.select("g");

const zoom = d3.zoom()
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .scaleExtent([1, 8])
  .on("zoom", ({ transform }) => group.attr("transform", transform));

svg.call(zoom);
```

My intention is to **ease** the standard drag behaviour.

I can't find any references for this in the docs, only this [specific example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/smooth-zooming?collection=@d3/d3-zoom) which implements programmatic zoom.

The aforementioned observable uses `.attrTween("transform", () => t => {}` and `d3.interpolateZoom(currentTransform, [])` to achieve this (I'm not going to lie, I am a bit lost in these matrix zoom operations).

My guess would be I'd have to access and manipulate the drag behaviour through the `.on("zoom")` callback.